# Client to WCF: Passing an enum value always gets 0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, enums

I have the following code written in the service.

```
[DataContract]
public class Email
{
    private string senderEmail;
    private MyEmailType emailType;

    [DataMember]
    public string SenderEmail { get { return senderEmail; } set { senderEmail = value; } }
    [DataMember]
    public MyEmailType EmailType { get { return emailType; } set { emailType = value; } }
}

[DataContract]
public enum MyEmailType
{
    [EnumMember]
    EmailType1 = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    EmailType2= 2
}
```

I send Email objects to the service like this:

```
Email email = new Email();
email.SenderEmail = "someemail@mail.com";
email.EmailType = MyEmailType.EmailType1;

bool isDispatchSuccessful = myClientObject.SendMassProcessEmail(email);
```

When I get to the service, the SenderEmail property's value is correct, but the EmailType (the enum one) gets 0, instead of 1 (EmailType1).

Why is this happening?

**Edit:**

I tried passing a MyEmailType variable besides the Email object to the SendMassProcessEmail like this:

```
bool isDispatchSuccessful = myClientObject.SendMassProcessEmail(email, MyEmailType.EmailType1);
```

Now, the stand-alone enum variable receives a correct value, but the one which is a public member of the Email class still gets a value of 0.

Comment: Have you used a tool (like Fiddler) to check what is being sent to the service? This will tell you if the problem is on the sender end or receiver end.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem yet.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question ill refer you to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875(v=vs.110).aspx

If you really want to pass the actual value i think you should do it like this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyEmailType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = 1)]
    EmailType1 = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = 2)]
    EmailType2= 2
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's still not working. Morover, you cannot assign integer values for the Value property of the EnumMember. The value property has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the [DataContract] to your backing fields:

```
[DataContract]
public class Email
{
    [DataMember]
    private string senderEmail;

    [DataMember]
    private MyEmailType emailType;

    public string SenderEmail { get { return senderEmail; } set { senderEmail = value; } }
    public MyEmailType EmailType { get { return emailType; } set { emailType = value; } }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer ist still a correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble but in my case, it was a mistake in the parameter name.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISendMail
{
    /// <summary />
    /// <param name="emailType">This parameter should be 'myEmailType'</param>
    [OperationContract]
    void Send(string senderEmail, MyEmailType emailType);
}
```

In my case, the second parameter was myEmailType on the server side, but, when I created the interface on the client, I forgot the 'my'. A stupid mistake that can bring some light to this question.